# Pseudo dual port RAM in verilog

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, ram, sram, asic

How does one design a pseudo dual port RAM using a single port RAM in Verilog ? What are the design considerations? Are there frequency limitations ?

Clarification on 'pseudo dual port - single port RAM (1RW) with external logic' to make it appear like dual port RAM (1R/1W).

Comment: What's a 'pseudo' dual port RAM?

Comment: Welcome new user. Think how you would design a circuit to do this. Ignore Verilog to start.

Comment: Arbitration. With only one port, only one thing can read and write at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your 'pseudo dual port' is what I often hear as "simple dual-port" i.e. one write port and one read port.

Since I see you tagged with 'ASIC' I doubt this will be complete nonetheless I think it would be useful to consider FPGA solution as proposed by [Xilinx (UG901)](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2020_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) as an example. There are many possible variations you are encouraged to check, especially when it comes to read-write ordering.

**Simple Dual-Port Block RAM with Single Clock (Verilog)**

```
module simple_dual_one_clock (clk,ena,enb,wea,addra,addrb,dia,dob);
input clk,ena,enb,wea;
input [9:0] addra,addrb;
input [15:0] dia;
output [15:0] dob;
reg [15:0] ram [1023:0];
reg [15:0] doa,dob;

always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (ena) begin
    if (wea)
      ram[addra] <= dia;
  end
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (enb)
    dob <= ram[addrb];
end

endmodule
```

I have just dumped the code from the original documentation. I'm not particularly fond of the indentation, the use of `reg` or the i/o declaration but that's it.

As far as I know in ASICs you should be using foundry cells (I honestly hope those basic constructs can go through).